# Is there way to delete (modify) parent element in plotly dash using pattern matching callbacks?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have modified example from [dash community](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-v1-11-0-release-introducing-pattern-matching-callbacks/37592/2) to show so called "3-level" dependencies of pattern matching callbacks.

##### what i've modified?

- For each chosen country , you can `add-chart` in added `chart-area`.
- added `delete` button for each added chart.

##### Question?

- how to delete definite chart from definite area??

```py
import os

import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, MATCH, ALL
from flask import Flask

df = px.data.gapminder()
mine_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
mine_dir = os.path.join(mine_dir, 'instance')
srv = Flask(__name__, instance_path=mine_dir)

external_js = ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
               "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True, server=srv, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CERULEAN],
                external_scripts=external_js)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(
            options=[{
                'label': i,
                'value': i
            } for i in df.country.unique()],
            value='Canada',
            id='country',
            style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': 200}
        ),
        html.Button(
            'Add Chart area ', id='add-chart-area', n_clicks=0,
            style={'display': 'inline-block'}
        ),
        html.Div(id='del-me-please', children=[]) # attempt to add `independent` div element and store here ids to be removed by another callback. 
    ]),

    html.Div(id='container', children=[])
])


def create_figure(column_x, column_y, country):
    chart_type = px.line if column_x == 'year' else px.scatter
    return chart_type(
        df.query("country == '{}'".format(country)),
        x=column_x,
        y=column_y,
    ) \
        .update_layout(
        title='{} {} vs {}'.format(country, column_x, column_y),
        margin_l=10, margin_r=0, margin_b=30) \
        .update_xaxes(title_text='').update_yaxes(title_text='')


@app.callback(
    Output('container', 'children'),
    Input('add-chart-area', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('del-me-please', 'children'),
    State('container', 'children'),
    State('country', 'value'))
def display_dropdowns(n_clicks, to_del, children, country):
    if n_clicks:
        new_element = html.Details(id={
            'type': 'dynamic-details',
            'index': country
        }, style={"marginLeft": "5px", "marginTop": "10px", 'width': '23%', 'display': 'inline-block',
                  'outline': 'thin lightgrey solid', 'padding': 10},
            open=True, children=[

                html.Summary(children=f"dynamic-details for country : {country}"),
                html.Div(children=[
                    html.Button(
                        'Add Chart', id={
                            'type': 'add-chart',
                            'index': country
                        }, n_clicks=0,
                        style={'display': 'inline-block'}, className="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
                    ),

                ], style={"marginLeft": "10px"})
            ])
        children.append(new_element)
    if to_del:
        res = []
        for kid in children:
            if kid == to_del:
                continue
            else:
                res.append(kid)
        return res
    return children


@app.callback(
    Output({'type': 'dynamic-details', 'index': MATCH}, 'children'),
    Input({'type': 'add-chart', 'index': MATCH}, 'n_clicks'),
    State({'type': 'dynamic-details', 'index': MATCH}, 'children'),
    State({'type': 'dynamic-details', 'index': MATCH}, 'id'),
)
def display_charts(n_clicks, children, id):
    if not n_clicks:
        return children

    country = id.get('index')

    default_column_x = 'year'
    default_column_y = 'gdpPercap'
    new_element = html.Div(id={
        'type': 'chart-div-area',
        'index': country + str(n_clicks),
        'parent': country

    },
        style={'width': '23%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'outline': 'thin lightgrey solid', 'padding': 10},
        children=[
            html.Button(
                'Delete chart', id={
                    'type': 'dell-chart',
                    'index': country + str(n_clicks),
                    'parent': country
                }, n_clicks=0,
                style={'display': 'inline-block'}, className="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
            ),
            html.Div(id={
                'type': 'deller_hidden_div',
                'index': country + str(n_clicks),  
                'parent': country # attempt ot add 3-d level index. let call it `parent`
            }, children=[]),
            dcc.Graph(
                id={
                    'type': 'dynamic-output',
                    'index': country + str(n_clicks),
                    'parent': country
                },
                style={'height': 300},
                figure=create_figure(default_column_x, default_column_y, country)
            ),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id={
                    'type': 'dynamic-dropdown-x',
                    'index': country + str(n_clicks),
                    'parent': country
                },
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.columns],
                value=default_column_x
            ),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id={
                    'type': 'dynamic-dropdown-y',
                    'index': country + str(n_clicks),
                    'parent': country
                },
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.columns],
                value=default_column_y
            ),
        ]
    )
    children.append(new_element)
    return children


@app.callback(
    Output({'type': 'dynamic-output', 'index': MATCH}, 'figure'),
    Input({'type': 'dynamic-dropdown-x', 'index': MATCH}, 'value'),
    Input({'type': 'dynamic-dropdown-y', 'index': MATCH}, 'value'),
    Input('country', 'value'),

)
def display_output(column_x, column_y, country):
    return create_figure(column_x, column_y, country)


@app.callback(
    Output('del-me-please', 'children'),
    Input({'type': 'dell-chart', 'index': ALL, 'parent': ALL}, 'n_clicks'),
    State({'type': 'dell-chart', 'index': ALL, 'parent': ALL}, 'id'),
)
def my_shiny_remover(n_clicks, id_):
# SOME MAGIC HERE
    res = []
    if not n_clicks:
        return res
    parent = id_.get('parent')
    """
    try to create div with elements I want to delete in separate div element and index of 
    "parent" div. At this approach, I get that element does not exist.
    """
    new_el = html.Div(id={'type': 'need-to-del', 'index': parent}, children=id_)
    res.append(new_el)
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

- example code in action
  [image: example code in action]
- What I want to trigger: e.g. remove 2-d chart from Canada section. without touching any other charts for any country.
  [image: What i want to trigger]

#### What i've tried:

- different combinations of `MATCH` `ALL` patterns. No success. getting

```
  del-me-please.children
State 0 ({"index":MATCH,"parent":MATCH,"type":"dell-chart"}.id)
has MATCH or ALLSMALLER on key(s) index, parent
where Output 0 (del-me-please.children)
does not have a MATCH wildcard. Inputs and State do not
need every MATCH from the Output(s), but they cannot have
extras beyond the Output(s).
```

- Attempt to add `3-d level` index called `parent`(<- name doesn't matter) with parent div `index`. same error as in first time, or smth like this `Output should have MATCH...`
- Attempt to add `independent` `Div` in base layout. no success - as `MATCH` of  `INPUT` requires `MATCH` output. but independent div `del-me-please` has no pattern in its id.
- Attempt to add `independent` pattern match div element in same dynamic div, where corresponding elemnts are exist `deller_hidden_div` in my example. and in `my shiny remover` append div with `index` == `parent` element (country chosen in may case).

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem and did not find a perfectly matching solution for it, BUT:
The source of the problem is that a dash callback can only accept properties of an object, not the object itself.
Therefore we can avoid the limitation by using one delete button and checkbox for each item. To be more concrete, I inserted the relevant example from https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, MATCH, ALL

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div('Dash To-Do list'),
    dcc.Input(id="new-item"),
    html.Button("Add", id="add"),
    html.Button("Clear Done", id="clear-done"),
    html.Div(id="list-container"),
    html.Div(id="totals")
])

style_todo = {"display": "inline", "margin": "10px"}
style_done = {"textDecoration": "line-through", "color": "#888"}
style_done.update(style_todo)


@app.callback(
    [
        Output("list-container", "children"),
        Output("new-item", "value")
    ],
    [
        Input("add", "n_clicks"),
        Input("new-item", "n_submit"),
        Input("clear-done", "n_clicks")
    ],
    [
        State("new-item", "value"),
        State({"index": ALL}, "children"),
        State({"index": ALL, "type": "done"}, "value")
    ]
)
def edit_list(add, add2, clear, new_item, items, items_done):
    triggered = [t["prop_id"] for t in dash.callback_context.triggered]
    adding = len([1 for i in triggered if i in ("add.n_clicks", "new-item.n_submit")])
    clearing = len([1 for i in triggered if i == "clear-done.n_clicks"])
    new_spec = [
        (text, done) for text, done in zip(items, items_done)
        if not (clearing and done)
    ]
    if adding:
        new_spec.append((new_item, []))
    new_list = [
        html.Div([
            dcc.Checklist(
                id={"index": i, "type": "done"},
                options=[{"label": "", "value": "done"}],
                value=done,
                style={"display": "inline"},
                labelStyle={"display": "inline"}
            ),
            html.Div(text, id={"index": i}, style=style_done if done else style_todo)
        ], style={"clear": "both"})
        for i, (text, done) in enumerate(new_spec)
    ]
    return [new_list, "" if adding else new_item]


@app.callback(
    Output({"index": MATCH}, "style"),
    Input({"index": MATCH, "type": "done"}, "value")
)
def mark_done(done):
    return style_done if done else style_todo


@app.callback(
    Output("totals", "children"),
    Input({"index": ALL, "type": "done"}, "value")
)
def show_totals(done):
    count_all = len(done)
    count_done = len([d for d in done if d])
    result = "{} of {} items completed".format(count_done, count_all)
    if count_all:
        result += " - {}%".format(int(100 * count_done / count_all))
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Hope, it helps, waiting for a real solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30316383)